# Keeping divs from overlapping on resize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize

These divs have an image with overlapped text, which looks how I want it to at full size.

However, when I resize down to small mobile size the text goes to the top of the image and the divs overlap.

How can I make this so that on resize the text goes to the bottom of the image, but most importantly, the containers don't overlap?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  clear:both;
}

.text-block {
 clear:both;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  clear:both;
}

.text-block {
 clear:both;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<p>How to place text blocks over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="Nature" style="width:90%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Nature</h4>
    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="Nature" style="width:90%;">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Nature</h4>
    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>
  
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow the block level elements (`.text-blocks`) to stack as they naturally will for small viewports. Then apply absolute positioning after your preferred breakpoint using a media query.

```css
.container {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-block {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

@media ( min-width: 48em ) {
  .container {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .container img {
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .text-block {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Image Text Blocks</h2>
<p>How to place text blocks over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="Nature">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Nature</h4>
    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="Nature">
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Nature</h4>
    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes that problem! I do have one question though. Can I keep this format on mobile but have the text block still overlap on the bottom of the image? So image one (in container one) would have the text block overlap the bottom then there would be a break between container one and container two still?

Comment: Yes/No. The issue with doing the overlay on mobile, especially a viewport that is `360px` wide, is the overlay is likely going to hide a large portion, if not all, of the image. You could reduce the font size, but how far do you go with that so users don't struggle to read your text? What if you have a long title and description in the overlay? That's going to increase the size of the overlay - hiding more of the image. To get it to work you'll have to have some rules. Like on small viewports you could hide the description of the overlay and try keeping the title short.